"+" in file permissions
I back up my stuff with rsync over private/public-keyed SSH, to /media/pi/backups/...    to a Raspberry PI with a 1GB USB HD plugged into it as the occasional, offsite backups.
When I look at the backup directories on the PI,
some directories have appeared.
root@backupPi:/media/pi# ls -la /media/pi
total 20
drwxr-x---+ 5 pi   pi   4096 Apr 12  2024 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 21  2019 ..
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Feb 20  2023 data
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Feb 20  2023 data1
drwxr-xr-x  9 pi   pi   4096 Dec 13  2023 data2

root@backupPi:/media/pi/data1# ls -la
total 8
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Feb 20  2023 .
drwxr-x---+ 5 pi   pi   4096 Apr 12  2024 ..

... and all my stuff is in data2 (although it would have gone initially into /media/pi/data.)
The + signifies ACL, according to File Permissions mode ending in @ or +, but I can't find anything more about it.
How has the + been added?
How do I find out what the ACL involves?

Can you share the command you used please. It will help identify if you've copied existing ACLs from the source

You do not need getfacl/setfacl to modify extended permissions - noting here your comment below.  It can be done by any software which makes the correct sys calls. If your installation on the RPi does not have those programs installed, then you need to install the acl package. This should have been installed by default.


and all my stuff is in data2 ( although it would have gone initially into /media/pi/data)

Someone wiggled the USB cable and the USB device got disconnected while some files under /media/pi/data were still in use, so the filesystem couldn't be unmounted even though the device was gone. When the device re-appeared, /media/pi/data was still taken by the previous mount, so UDisks2 decided to mount the new device on /media/pi/data1 instead.
Or something like that. The file permissions of those subdirectories imply that the filesystem did get unmounted eventually, though, but UDisks2 (or whatever you use for mounting disks) didn't properly clean up the mountpoint directories after.

How has the + been added ?

It might have been there from the beginning.
The line corresponds to the . entry, meaning /media/pi itself – not related to any specific disk, but rather the parent directory which contains the automatic disk mountpoints. It's automatically created by UDisks2 which also sets some permissions so that only you can access the disks you connect.

how do i find out what the ACL involves ?

Use the getfacl program. If you don't have getfacl, install it. (Usually the package is called acl.)

how have the permissions been set if the program isnt in the system ?

The program doesn't set the permissions; the program is a frontend for the system function that sets permissions. That system call isn't somehow limited to the /bin/setfacl program alone – other programs, such as systemd or rsync, can directly use the same system call without necessarily having to go through a dedicated program, in much the same way as they can change the regular file modes without actually running /bin/chmod

thanks - very succinct explanation. The offsite backups is at my sons' place. So i can blame my 4yo grandson !

I had same problem on Solaris.
The man pages are for a program called setfacl. It is an entirely different land of file perms, happy reads!!

thanks . but when i try it on my pi for sudo getfacl  and sudo setfacl I get " command not found".  So how have the permissions been set if the program isnt in the system ?

Ok, heres what I know, it can only be a hint:  facls are totally adjunct to the entire filesystem (meaning if one is enabled they are necessarily enabled for any file, maybe none):  oh, btw;  try on the Pi for man getfacl or man -k facl
